# How to put mutli observables in one observable in RxJava?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have mutli obserables of type Observable I want to put them all in one Obseravble and observe this one only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want each Observable to be done and then going to the next Observable (In Sequence) then you can use:

```
Obserable.concat(Obseravble<T>, Obserable<T>, Obserable<T>)
```

If you don't care about their sequence you can use:

```
Obserable.merge(Obseravble<T>, Obserable<T>, Obserable<T>)
```

Note: You can observe them both in the normal way.